# Understanding operations on composed functor types

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

According to several sources, the Haskell implementation for composing functors is more or less the following:

```
import Data.Functor.Compose

newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) x)
```

My question is: **what is the type of x in the last definition?**

I'd say it is `f g a`, but even there I struggle to 'see' the computation `fmap (fmap f) x`

Could anyone be as kind as to provide a clear and complete working example of this point? What about fmapping a `Tree` of `Maybe`'s paying attention to both `Empty`'s and `Node`'s?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `x` is `f (g a)`. For example, `x` might be a list of trees of integers: `[Tree Int]` (which can also be written as `[] (Tree Int)` so that it matches `f (g x)` more closely).

As an example, consider function `succ :: Int -> Int` which adds one to an integer. Then, function `fmap succ :: Tree Int -> Tree Int` will increment every integer in the tree. Further, `fmap (fmap succ) :: [Tree Int] -> [Tree Int]` will apply the previous `fmap succ` to all the trees in a list, hence it will increment every integer in the list of trees.

If instead you have `Tree (Maybe Int)`, then `fmap (fmap succ)` will increment every integer in such tree. Values in the tree of the form `Nothing` will not be affected, while values `Just x` will have `x` incremented.

Example: (GHCi session)

```
> :set -XDeriveFunctor
> data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty deriving (Show, Functor)
> let x1 = [Node 1 Empty Empty]
> fmap (fmap succ) x1
[Node 2 Empty Empty]
> let x2 = [Node 1 Empty Empty, Node 2 (Node 3 Empty Empty) Empty]
> fmap (fmap succ) x2
[Node 2 Empty Empty,Node 3 (Node 4 Empty Empty) Empty]
> let x3 = Just (Node 1 Empty Empty)
> fmap (fmap succ) x3
Just (Node 2 Empty Empty)
```

Comment: Here is what I'm typing in:
*Main > let x1 = [Node 1 Empty Empty]
*Main > let x2 = x1 fmap (fmap succ)
ERROR!
What I am doing wrong? Now I try with the Maybe....

Comment: Still unable to make it work: *Main> let y1 = Node (Just 1) Empty Empty *Main> let y2 = y1 fmap (fmap succ) ERROR!

Comment: That's why I asked explicitly for a "clear and complete working example". Thank you!

Comment: OK, I goofed big time with x1/y1 in front of the fmappings. But I KNEW there had to be some trick under the hood. This time is -XDeriveFunctor.

Comment: @Muzietto You can avoid `-XDeriveFunctor` if you manually define a functor instance. However, since GHC now can derive that automatically, it's more convenient to just let it do that.

Answer (score 18):

> what is the type of x in the last definition?

Before saying anything else about the matter: you can ask GHC! GHC 7.8 and above supports `TypedHoles`, meaning that if you place an underscore in a expression (not pattern), and hit load or compile, you get a message with the expected type of the underscore and the types of the variables in local scope.

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose x) = _
```

GHC says now, with some parts omitted:

```
Notes.hs:6:26: Found hole ‘_’ with type: Compose f g b …
    -- omitted type variable bindings --
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: f (g a)
        (bound at /home/kutta/home/Dropbox/src/haskell/Notes.hs:6:21)
      f :: a -> b
        (bound at /home/kutta/home/Dropbox/src/haskell/Notes.hs:6:10)
      fmap :: (a -> b) -> Compose f g a -> Compose f g b
        (bound at /home/kutta/home/Dropbox/src/haskell/Notes.hs:6:5)
    In the expression: _
    In an equation for ‘fmap’: fmap f (Compose x) = _
    In the instance declaration for ‘Functor (Compose f g)’
```

There you go, `x :: f (g a)`. And after some practice, `TypedHoles` can help you tremendously in figuring out complex polymorphic code. Let's try to figure out our current code out by writing out the right hand side from scratch.

We've already seen that the hole had type `Compose f g b`. Therefore we must have a `Compose _` on the right side:

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose x) = Compose _
```

The new hole has type `f (g b)`. Now we should look at the context:

```
Relevant bindings include
  x :: f (g a)
    (bound at /home/kutta/home/Dropbox/src/haskell/Notes.hs:6:21)
  f :: a -> b
    (bound at /home/kutta/home/Dropbox/src/haskell/Notes.hs:6:10)
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> Compose f g a -> Compose f g b
    (bound at /home/kutta/home/Dropbox/src/haskell/Notes.hs:6:5)
```

The goal is to get an `f (g b)` out of the ingredients in the context. The `fmap` in the listing above unfortunately refers to the function being defined, which is sometimes helpful, but not here. We're better off knowing that `f` and `g` are both functors, therefore they can be `fmap`-ed over. Since we have `x :: f (g a)`, we guess that we should `fmap` something over `x` to get an `f (g b)`:

```
fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap _ x)
```

Now the hole becomes `g a -> g b`. But `g a -> g b` is very easy now, since we have `f :: a -> b` and `g` is a `Functor`, so we also have `fmap :: (a -> b) -> g a -> g b`, and therefore `fmap f :: g a -> g b`.

```
fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) x)
```

And we're done.

To wrap up the technique:

1. Start with putting a hole in the place where you don't know how to proceed. Here we started with putting the hole in place of the entire right hand side, but often you will have a good idea about most parts of an implementation and you'll need the hole in a specific problematic subexpression.
2. By looking at the types, try to narrow down which implementations could possibly lead to the goal and which could not. Fill in a new expression and reposition the hole. In proof assistant jargon this is called "refining".
3. Repeat step 2 until you either have the goal, in which case you're done, or the current goal seems impossible, in which case backtrack until the last non-obvious choice you made, and try an alternative refining.

The above technique is sometimes facetiously called "type tetris". A possible drawback is that you can implement complex code just by playing the "tetris", without actually understanding what you're doing. And sometimes after going too far, you get seriously stuck in the game, and then you have to start actually thinking about the problem. But ultimately it lets you understand code that would be otherwise very difficult to grasp.

I personally use `TypedHoles` *all the time* and basically as a reflex. I've come to rely so much on it so that on a occasion when I had to move  back to GHC 7.6 I felt rather uncomfortable (but fortunately you [can emulate holes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52VsgyexS8Q) even there).

Comment: Great answer! They say teaching to fish is better than providing one fish. Thank you. Now I wonder if there's the possibility to specify which fmap belongs to the f instance and which to the g. I understand that the compiler is super-smart and infers that wonderfully, but humans are another thing...

Comment: "we guess that we should fmap something over x to get an f (g b)" - that's a key learning point.

Comment: @MarcoFaustinelli you can use a type application for that, and write `fmap @f`, `fmap @g`.